# Seeing default fulfillment code instead of the one hat it's used for the chatbot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm developing a chatbot with Dialogflow ES for a client.

**Situation:**

- The first phase of the chatbot is already developed (months ago)
- For the first phase I was using the fulfillment feature (through Inline editor) with quite a lot of custom code
- Now, after couple of months, I started implementing some updates to the chatbot

**Issue:**
If I go and try to see and update the fullfilment code, I see the deafult code in Inline editor instead of my custom code.

**Questions:**

- Has anyone experienced this?
- I'm thinking that one of the possible reasons could be the Dialogflow plan/version which is currently a "Free" one - although the free plan is basically just about the limits which we currently do not exceed. Could this be true?
- Or the other, more likely the right reson: I checked the settings in the Google Cloud Console and saw that the project's billing account is closed. As far as I can remember the client had to set up billing couple of months ago when we started with the chatbot development, for us to be able to use the fulfillment feature. Am I thinking correctly? Could setting up a billing again solve the issue?

**Additional question:** does anyone know if the old custom code will be available after I somehow
solve the issue above? I'm going to cry if I can't get the old code back:(

Thanks,
Boštjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the issue was indeed the billing which was closed. The billing is now set again and the fulfillment works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) of Dialogflow the inline editor deploys your code to the Cloud Functions. You can refer to the below mentioned steps to retrieve the last deployed code.

**Steps:**

- Go to your GCP Project
- Navigate to **Cloud Functions** in the GCP console
- Search for your Dialogflow inline editor function which will be named by **dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment**. This is the default name to be used if you are using an inline editor
- Click on the function
- Check for the  version. If you have not deployed the default code again, you can retrieve your last deployed code only
- Click on the source and then click on the Download as Zip option

[image]

This way you can retrieve your last deployed code.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).